# Determine swipe or tap

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to determine between tapping the screen and swiping the screen.
I want to determine swipes from left, right, up and down.
Right now when I swipe left or right, it also turns my player.
Which isn't suppose to happen. It should be one or the other, either turn or move left or right. My question is how can I determine all five things?
Swipe left, right, up, and down as-well as just tapping the screen.
Here is my code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class PlayerMotor : MonoBehaviour {

    private CharacterController controller;
    private Vector3 moveVector;
    private float speed = 2.0f;
    private float verticalVelocity = 0.0f;
    private float gravity = 12.0f;

    public Touch touch;

    private void Start() {

        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController> ();
    }
    private void Update() 
    {           
        moveVector = Vector3.zero;
        if (controller.isGrounded) 
        {
            verticalVelocity = -0.5f;
        } 
        else 
        {
            verticalVelocity -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButton (0)) 
        {
            if (touch.position.x == touch.deltaPosition.x && touch.position.x == touch.deltaPosition.x) 
            {   //3px accuracy, stationery :P
                moveVector.x = transform.forward.x * speed;
                transform.Rotate (new Vector3 (0, -90, 0));
            } 
            else if (touch.position.x != touch.deltaPosition.x && touch.position.x != touch.deltaPosition.x) 
            {
                if (Input.mousePosition.x > Screen.width / 2)
                    moveVector.x = speed;
                else
                    moveVector.x = -speed;
            }
        }
        moveVector.y = verticalVelocity;
        moveVector.z = transform.forward.z * speed;
        controller.Move (moveVector * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this code with a little bit of searching. ([Here](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/swipe-in-all-directions-touch-and-mouse.165416/))

Adding an `else` statement after all the `if (currentSwipe...)` statements should work to detect the click

```
//inside class
Vector2 firstPressPos;
Vector2 secondPressPos;
Vector2 currentSwipe;

public void Swipe()
{
     if(Input.touches.Length > 0)
     {
         Touch t = Input.GetTouch(0);

         if(t.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
         {
              //save began touch 2d point
             firstPressPos = new Vector2(t.position.x,t.position.y);
         }

         if(t.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
         {
              //save ended touch 2d point
             secondPressPos = new Vector2(t.position.x,t.position.y);

              //create vector from the two points
             currentSwipe = new Vector3(secondPressPos.x - firstPressPos.x, secondPressPos.y - firstPressPos.y);

             //normalize the 2d vector
             currentSwipe.Normalize();

             //swipe upwards
             if(currentSwipe.y > 0  currentSwipe.x > -0.5f  currentSwipe.x < 0.5f)
             {
                 Debug.Log("up swipe");
             }

             //swipe down
             if(currentSwipe.y < 0  currentSwipe.x > -0.5f  currentSwipe.x < 0.5f)
             {
                 Debug.Log("down swipe");
             }

             //swipe left
             if(currentSwipe.x < 0  currentSwipe.y > -0.5f  currentSwipe.y < 0.5f)
             {
                 Debug.Log("left swipe");
             }

             //swipe right
             if(currentSwipe.x > 0  currentSwipe.y > -0.5f  currentSwipe.y < 0.5f)
             {
                 Debug.Log("right swipe");
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Should if(currentSwipe.y > 0  currentSwipe.x > -0.5f  currentSwipe.x < 0.5f)
Be:
if(currentSwipe.y > 0  && currentSwipe.x > -0.5f  && currentSwipe.x < 0.5f)?
Otherwise it says expect ')'

Comment: and this class I should use in PointerClick if I want to swipe around and then click?